# Beamer: temporarily disable overlay within one frame

Tags: beamer, overlays

Suppose I have the following

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcommand*{\something}{
  \onslide<+-> this \onslide<+-> that
}

\newcommand*{\morething}{
  \onslide<+-> more
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \something

  \morething
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This will produce a bunch of slides in which `this`, `that`, and `more` appear consecutively. I would like to create a new command, or environment that temporarily disables animation. Let me call the hypothetical command `\disableanim`. Then, the following code would produce slides where `this` and `that` just appear simultaneously (i.e. no animation) but the animation in `\morething` is still preserved. Ideally, `\disableanim` should be effective for other overlay-aware commands as well.

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcommand*{\disableanim}{???}

\newcommand*{\something}{
  \onslide<+-> this \onslide<+-> that
}

\newcommand*{\morething}{
  \onslide<+-> more
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \disableanim{\something}

  \morething
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can temporarily replace `\onslide<.>` with a no-op in this:

```
\newcommand*{\disableanim}[1]{{%
  \RenewDocumentCommand{\onslide}{ R<>{} }{}%
  #1%
}}
```

Note the additional grouping `{`...`}` inside the macro that limits the scope of the redefinition. Similar redefinitions for other overlay-aware commands can be inserted as well.

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking about doing this as well. But I was hoping for a way to disable the overlay specification altogether since there are just too many overlay-aware commands to override.